# LMM Fine Tuning - Supervised Fine Tuning Trainer (SFTTrainer) vs transformers Trainer

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface, fine-tuning, large-language-model

When should one opt for the Supervised Fine Tuning Trainer (SFTTrainer) instead of the regular Transformers Trainer when it comes to instruction fine-tuning for Language Models (LLMs)? From what I gather, the regular Transformers Trainer typically refers to unsupervised fine-tuning, often utilized for tasks such as Input-Output schema formatting after conducting supervised fine-tuning. There seem to be various examples of fine-tuning tasks with similar characteristics, but with some employing the SFTTrainer and others using the regular Trainer. Which factors should be considered in choosing between the two approaches?

I looking for Fine Tuning a LLM for generating json to json transformation (matching texts in json) using huggingface and trl libraries.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Most probably people are going to close this issue since it's not coding related. Try asking it on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/, folks might be nicer there to ML recommendations.

Comment: Thanks @alvas. I asked it there https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/122164/lmm-fine-tuning-supervised-fine-tuning-trainer-sfttrainer-vs-transformers-tr